# React-native and Expo: shake sensor component for Android

Tags: react-native, expo, android-sensors

I am a complete newbie to React Native and Expo, and want to experiment with the Accelerometer component to build a magic 8-ball game where the user gets the answer to a question when shaking their android.

I have the fetch in a component that I call MagicAnswer.js and now want to connect that one to the ShakeSensor.js I guess that I need to do some restructuring around in the components but was hoping that I could call the ShakeSensor within StartPage to show the Magic Answer on a shake, but my current problem is that the answer does not stay on the screen.

I updated to this (see code below): isShaking(data) &&

```
// ShakeSensor.js component: 
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Accelerometer } from 'expo-sensors';
import styled from 'styled-components/native';

import { MagicAnswer } from './MagicAnswer'

// ==========================
// = Functions
const isShaking = (data) => {
  const totalForce = Math.abs(data.x) + Math.abs(data.y) + Math.abs(data.z);
  return totalForce > 1.78;
};

// ==========================
// = Styled components
const ShakeView = styled.View`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
`;

const ShakeAlert = styled.Text`
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #aa0000;
`;
const ShakeDataView = styled.View``;
const ShakeDataTitle = styled.Text`
  font-weight: bold;
`;
const ShakeData = styled.Text``;

export const ShakeSensor = () => {
  Accelerometer.setUpdateInterval(400);

  const [data, setData] = useState({
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    z: 0,
  });

  const [subscription, setSubscription] = useState(null);

  const _subscribe = () => {
    setSubscription(
      Accelerometer.addListener((accelerometerData) => {
        setData(accelerometerData);
      })
    );
  };

  const _unsubscribe = () => {
    subscription && subscription.remove();
    setSubscription(null);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    _subscribe();

    return () => _unsubscribe();
  }, []);

  return (
    <ShakeView>
      {isShaking(data) && <MagicAnswer></MagicAnswer>}
      <ShakeDataView>
        <ShakeDataTitle>Shake Data</ShakeDataTitle>

        <ShakeData>X: {data.x.toFixed(2)}</ShakeData>
        <ShakeData>Y: {data.y.toFixed(2)}</ShakeData>
        <ShakeData>Z: {data.z.toFixed(2)}</ShakeData>
      </ShakeDataView>
    </ShakeView>
  )
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Are there any errors?

Comment: I have updated my OP. And tried out just mounting my MagicAnswer.js inside of ShakeSensor.js. My problem is understanding how to get the MagicAnswer to stay on the screen.

Comment: What do you mean that the answer doesn't stay on the screen? So it appears and then disappears, and you want to keep it?

Comment: Yes, I tried `{isShaking(data) && <MagicAnswer></MagicAnswer>}
 {isShaking(data) && _unsubscribe()} ` but that creates too many loops.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well, you want to display your `MagicAnswer` after the phone has been shaked. In your current setup, it is only shown when the `isShaking` fn is returning true.

That means that once the phone is not being shaked, you are not showing the component anymore.

One alternative would be to show your `MagicAnswer` when fields in `data` are not 0 and then reset them when you are starting to shake your phone again.

So something like

```
  {data.x != 0 && data.y != 0 && <MagicAnswer></MagicAnswer>}
```

And then when the phone is still, your values are reset.

If not, you can keep the values until you do the next shake -> so in your listener, instead of setting the values to state straight away, you could take a fn and compare total force. If the total force changes - set it to data and show your new MagicAnswer.

Comment: I tried `const isShaking = (data) => {
  const [sumTotalForce, setSumTotalForce] = useState(0)
  const totalForce = Math.abs(data.x) + Math.abs(data.y) + Math.abs(data.z);
  if (totalForce > 1.5) {
    setSumTotalForce(totalForce)
    setTimeout(() => { setSumTotalForce(0) }, 5000)
  } 
  return sumTotalForce > 1.5
}`

Comment: and in the return just rendered {isShaking(data) && <MagicAnswer></MagicAnswer>} But this also gives an Error with too many re-renders. I guess I have add the setTimeOut within a useEffect?

Comment: Have you solved it? If not, can you please modify the question with the latest changes that you did?